# Need a hand with joins SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hi guys so what I think I have to do is a double join, but I have done some research and still I am not quite sure how to do it ... hope you guys can give me a hand. So below are my tables.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you probably see, the empresa is related to empresa_id on the second table, and id_user from the third table is related to id of the second table.

I've already done this query :

```
select users.username, COUNT(*) c
from form_reply
    left join users on form_reply.id_user = users.id
GROUP BY id
```

but it only retrieves the number of rows of each user and I also want it's "empresa". I am expecting an output like this :

```
+--------+-+----------+
|Username|c| empresa  |
+--------+-+----------+
|   su   |7|AccSystems|
+--------+-+----------+
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use another join with empressa_table to combine 3 tables

```
select users.username,e.empresa, COUNT(*) c
from form_reply
    join users on form_reply.id_user = users.id
    join empressa_table e on users.empresa_id=e.id
GROUP BY users.username,e.empresa
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, there's only a mistake on "empressa_table" wich should be empresas. Thank you again !! @Fahmi